# Using init as copy converter in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I am writing some code that uses Temperatures. So I wanted a class that would hold the scale being used (C/F) and the value. I made the class immutable (by using a category in the implementation class). I wanted a converter. In Java, we would generally do a static method and have it return a new instance, but you can't do that in O-C because + methods are class methods and don't have access to instance properties.

So I did an init method that takes the current Temperature instance and the scale we want it converted to. Having done C++ for a long time, this is like a copy constructor.

Question here is whether there is a better way or something that would be considered standard practice. So to get a conversion you would do:

```
Temperature *freezingF = [[Temperature alloc]initWithScale:Fahrenheit andValue:@32.0];
Temperature *freezingC = [[Temperature alloc]initWith:freezingF andScale:Celsius];

assertThat(freezingC.value, is(@0));
```

(Shortened the variable names to limit scrolling...)

Comment: A class method can access the private ivars of instances of the same class. You use the `->` syntax. `someInstance->_someIvar`.

Comment: There was an answer on here saying + methods could not since they were class methods.. What about NSNumber's example, it has all the numberWith____ methods which are basically class factories.

Comment: All of the `numberWithXXX` methods are convenience wrappers around the corresponding `alloc / initWithXXX` methods. I wouldn't call them factory methods.

Comment: Yeah, so more compact syntax, but that makes my original argument that the init is the copy constructor of record in O-C.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a `convertTo:` instance method that returns a new immutable temperature instance in the new unit?

```
- (Temperature *)convertTo:(TemperatureScale)scale {
    float newValue = ... // calculate new value
    return [[Temperature alloc] initWithScale:scale andValue:newValue];
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
Temperature *freezingF = [[Temperature alloc]initWithScale:Fahrenheit andValue:@32.0];
Temperature *freezingC = [freezingF convertTo:Celsius];
```

Comment: Mainly just because it makes me feel like I'm making an instance into a factory.. ?

Comment: Look at every instance method of `NSString` that returns a new `NSString` as an example. This would be no different.

Comment: Although NSString also has a copy constructor. The other way to look at this would be potentially that what is being returned is an immutable representation of the original, e.g. just a copy with a different scale, in which case it's not really a factory..

Answer (score 3):

I would store the backing value in Kelvin or C, then use `setters` and `getters`, `setKValue:` `setFValue:` and `kValue`, `fValue`. because they are basically the same value in different units

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussion here, another choice would be:

```
+(Temperature *)convert:(Temperature *)from toScale:(TemperatureScale)newScale;
```

which would be called like this:

```
Temperature *freezingF = [[Temperature alloc]initWithScale:Fahrenheit andValue:@32];
Temperature *freezingC = [Temperature convert:freezingF toScale:Celsius];
```

This is based on the NSNumber class method examples: numberWithFloat, Int, etc.

Comment: Using a class method for this is a bad design. You want to perform an action on an existing instance. Therefore it should be an instance method. Your proposed use of a class method here is nothing like the various `numberWithXXX` methods of `NSNumber`.